# Transitively copy dlls in a CMake project

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, shared-libraries, visual-studio-2017

Let's say I have a CMake project with two libraries `foo` and `bar`, and an executable `app`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(app)

add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)
add_library(bar SHARED bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app foo)
```

So first, when I try to compile this project on Windows, it failed with an error `LNK1104 - cannot open file 'bar.lib'`. What am I doing wrong? I mean, this is like the most basic example ever, how can it fail? I am compiling with Visual Studio 15.4.2 (MSVC 14.11.25503), and CMake 3.9.1.

Next question, I want my `foo.dll` and `bar.dll` to be automatically copied to the folder where `app.exe` will be compiled (I assume it will be `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:app>`). Can I do that *by adding properties/custom commands to `foo` and `bar` without modifying the way that `foo` and `bar` are linked to `app`?*

In other words, I want to modify the above script so that, if I add a new target executable `app2`, a simple call to `target_link_libraries(app2 foo)` is *all I need* to have my `foo.dll` and `bar.dll` copied over to the destination folder of `app2`.

The problem I have so far is that existing solutions involving  `add_custom_command( ... COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ... )` requires to be added to the *final* target `app` and `app2` explicitly, I cannot just `add_custom_command(foo ...)` because `app` and `app2` can end up in arbitrary folders.

I was thinking of maybe modifying the `target_link_libraries(app ...)` to wrap a call to my own function (the one that copies dll) and call the old `_target_link_libraries(app ...)`, but I am not sure if that's the cleanest way to go, and was wondering if there are better ways to it.

Finally, I would like whatever solution we find to also work with `IMPORTED` targets and libraries that are not compiled as CMake subprojects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So first, when I try to compile this project on Windows, it failed
>   with an error LNK1104 - cannot open file 'bar.lib'. What am I doing
>   wrong?

Your library does not export anything, that's why it's not creating an import library (the `.lib` file that he's complaining about). Be sure your source files actually define some symbols and then be sure that those symbols are actually exported from the DLL. CMake even ships with [a module that provides portable macros for exporting symbols](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/GenerateExportHeader.html).

> Next question, I want my foo.dll and bar.dll to be automatically
>   copied to the folder where app.exe will be compiled (I assume it will
>   be $). Can I do that by adding properties/custom
>   commands to foo and bar without modifying the way that foo and bar are
>   linked to app?

Unfortunately, CMake does not have proper support for runtime dependency management at the moment. That's what prevents this from working with a simple call to `target_link_libraries`. Such a feature has been discussed several times already among the CMake developers but it seems surprisingly hard to get right (I'm not too familiar with the details here though).

The most convenient method that I could come up with is having the providing library provide a CMake [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/function.html) that copies all the relevant DLLs to a folder provided to it as an argument. It's still a pain, but at least you keep the details about which DLLs to copy with the providing library.

Comment: I implemented this approach of providing a function for copying the DLLs in [one of my github projects](https://github.com/ComicSansMS/GhulbusBase/blob/master/cmake/gbBaseMacros.cmake.in). The overall mechanism is quite complex, as it is tightly coupled to the [config-file packaging system](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#config-file-packages), but maybe it will help to illustrate the extent of support that you can get from CMake in this matter.

Comment: Thanks. I've already implemented a similar function (which is pretty much a verbatim copy of yours). i was hoping to find a more convenient solution that I had missed though.

Comment: I have the same problem and used your function, thx for that. It worked well for copying the dlls to the build directory of the exe, How can I make the copying happen also for the install process of the exe? Further it seems the function also copies *.libs if the imported library is not shared but static. Is there a way to avoid that?